# rails mailer generating invalid URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, rails-routing, railscasts

I am trying to add password reset functionality to my rails app using action mailer. Everything seems to be working fine except that the generated link to reset the password is incorrect.

Here are the files:

`File user_mailer.rb`:

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "from@example.com"
  def password_reset(user)
    @user = user #make the user available in mailer template
    mail :to => user.email, :subject => "Password Reset"
  end
end
```

`File password_reset.text.erb` contains the following link:

`<%= edit_password_resets_url(@user.password_reset_token) %>`

I can see the user variable is passed properly as I get the email and token values. However, the URL generated in the mailer looks like the following:

```
http://localhost:3000/password_reset/edit.jo_jYhkjsdjskjdskYHJSDA
```

However, the expected value is like

```
http://localhost:3000/password_resets/jo_jYhkjsdjskjdskYHJSDA/edit
```

Have the following in `routes.rb`

```
resource :password_resets
```

Also, rake routes shows the following:

```
edit_password_resets GET /password_resets(.:format) password_resets#edit
```

What could be going wrong?

Note: I am following Ryan bates' rails casts #274

Comment: contains `resource :password_resets` in routes.rb. Updating the question too

Comment: What happens when you change it to `resources :password_resets`? (See [Singular resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources) in the routing guide.) Also, be aware that [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) is pretty much the standard solution to the "users need to authenticate" problem.

Comment: a restful route like yours expects an id, not a token

Comment: @willglynn, that seems to be the issue, when I updated to `resources`, it started showing other problems which I changed in a wrong way. Fixing them. Eventually want to move to devise, but am just begining and hence want to practice a bit before jumping on board with plugins..

Comment: willglynn, that is the issue and fixed. Please post it as answer and will accept. @apneadiving, that's true and in this context, this is treated as an id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like `config/routes.rb` contains `resource :password_resets` instead of `resources :password_resets`. As a [singular resource](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources), this would add an `edit_password_resets` route to `/password_resets/edit(.:format)`. Passing a value into `edit_password_resets_url` would map to `edit.<value>`, consistent with the symptom you describe.

Changing this to `resources :password_resets` should fix the issue. It will also rename the route to `edit_password_reset` -- singular because it applies to a member, rather than plural which would apply to the collection.